# External user upload file

Tags: rest-api, customer-community, files

We're trying to allow Customer Community Users to upload files using our portal.
When I try to use the REST API to upload a file I get a `403 Forbidden` response. The response body has `message":"API is disabled for this User","errorCode":"API_CURRENTLY_DISABLED`
The profile has `read`, `create` and `edit` privileges on the object to which we are trying to attach the file.

Comment: Isn't it available as default functionality? Why you creating your own rest api?

Comment: Because we are using a Site with our own JS frontend to upload the files to SF.

Comment: I think you're going to want to have an API user assigned to the actual integration to your web site where the upload is going to (that's what I think you're saying you're doing as opposed to using Salesforce Sites). I'd recommend trying configure it to use Named Credentials or something similar. You'll then need to create permissions to allow your community users to access the service.

Comment: I think it may be because I'm missing some kind of configuration to my site and/or community. For example, I can't share an existing file with a community user. Not via the Files tab (can't find any Community user) nor creating a `ContentDocumentLink` in code (INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was somehow able to resolve this.
I don't know exactly what did it (I was trying a *lot* of different things) but I can now use the REST API to upload files as a Customer Community User. It is probably a combination of the following:

- Activating `Apex REST Services` on the user profile
- Activating `API Enabled` on the user profile
- Activating `Portal User Visibility` in the Sharing Settings
- Activating `Community User Visibility` in the Sharing Settings
- Adding the Files tab to the profile and to the community
  (Probably not this one)